# SPWeb permissions inside RunWithElevatedPrivileges

Tags: event-receivers, spweb, runwithelevatedprivileges

Please consider following scenario:

```
public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
   SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
   {
       SPWeb web1 = properties.Web;  //this SPWeb object will have permissions of 
                                     //current user, regardless of running inside RWEP
       SPWeb web2 = properties.OpenWeb();  //what permissions has this SPWeb object?
    });
 }
```

In event receiver, if I want to use Web from properties, then it will have permissions of current user, regardless of RWEP block. That's why I always created new instance of SPSite and SPWeb inside of RWEP block.

What permissions will SPWeb object have, if it is returned from `OpenWeb()` method called inside of RWEP? Permissions of current user or permissions of System Account?

Comment: Current User, since the Site is in scope, and that one is opened as the current user

Answer (score 0):

Current user, because properties don't run under elevated privileges. But why you don't try it yourself? You wrote the code yourself, you only need to debug. :)